# View-specific server-calls in redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

We have a React / Redux application that usually fetches data via the "normal" way - a view calls a dispatcher, the dispatcher calls our server and dispatches an action with the result, which is then put into the state via a reducer.

Now, I'm creating a view that needs to call the server to get a custom URL based on a few properties. It's not global state at all - since it's just this view that's going to be using it.

It doesn't feel right to call the server from the view directly, but it doesn't feel right to put this data in the global state either.

What is the best practice in these kinds of situations?

Answer (score 2):

You could bypass the "biased standard" here and create an action/lib file to do the fetching for you, and then let the result of that promise (or callback) be the input to the dispatch you will continue with.

From the question you ask, I assume you are going to do this for more than one component? If so, I think that the mentioned approach will suffice.

Further, if you are only doing this for one component, it could be enough to just put that logic in the component, or in a parent container (HoC).

Comment: We already have a server.js that does the actual request, so I wouldn't have to deal with `fetch` and json-parsing anyhow. 

Note that both approaches would happen in a top level (connected) container element (like an OverviewPage component).

Using an HoC to load do this call for me could indeed be a good idea - it would let the view deal with view logic at least.